# Convert image color channels?

Tags: image-processing

So, I have an image and I want to be able to set the Red and Blue values so they're equal to the value of the Green in the image. This is because the image is entirely Green and I want it to appear White. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open your image in Gimp

```
sudo apt-get install gimp
```

and open <kbd>Colors</kbd> > <kbd>Levels</kbd> and adjust your values

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I was able to do this with IrfanView by simply viewing the channel "Green" which made the image white, all I had to do was save it. (Note: IrfanView is a Windows program, but It should run in wine.)